# Android Input field focus visible in model window

Tags: android

I have a web page in which we have some footer links, on click of any of link it opens in a model window and on clicking close button get closed.

One strange thing is happening, when testing in mobile device Android. On page if there are any input fields and if you open any footer link where on opened window if you tab just above input field location, you can see the focus ring of that field. How to resolve this? Is this a android bug?

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this what i did is I have disabled the input fields when modal window shows up and enabled back again all input fields when window closed down.

It seems to me Samsung Galaxy S11 2.3.6 specific issue.